# is posible to add (Searches related) on Google Custom Search CSE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, search-engine, google-custom-search

This is my code, what should I add here to show (Searches related)?

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '0045334152284----:94o-----uqo';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

Example:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not.
The related searches feature of Google Web Search is not available in Custom Search Engine.